# How to Access and edit KML file attributes on Google map using Android Studio. And save the updated data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm stuck on code to proceed next step in my android project. I severely try to find a sample code but couldn't find it yet. This is code that I have to add the KML layer to a google map in android studio API 29.i want to create a new field in KML layer attribute then field select and its data save to the Firebase in real-time. And also retrieve save data to show on the map as pop-out window. Please give me a sample code or link to resolve.

```
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
      

        try {


            KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap,R.raw.testkml, getApplicationContext());
            layer.addLayerToMap();




        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng homagama = new LatLng(6.8440, 80.0024);
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(homagama).title("Homagama"));
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(homagama));
        float zoomLevel = (float) 13.0;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(homagama, zoomLevel));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access KML properties by utilizing the `getProperty()` function. You can also call `hasProperty()` to check if it exists. You can check the sample on Google Maps KML documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml#properties

I hope this helps!

Comment: ok this is really help for me. I 'll  follow the link and thank you.